# If you start a timer, what happens when the user exits the app?

Tags: ios, flurry

On iOS, if you start a timer:

```
[Flurry logEvent:eventName withParameters:parameters timed:YES];
```

What happens if the user leaves the app and the session ends? Does the time get logged?

What happens if the user leaves the app and then returns before the session ends?

Comment: How about you try it and test it? It's not difficult isn't it?

Comment: Unhelpful answer, black maggie. If you're unfamiliar with Flurry, it takes a long time for data to filter in. That would make quite a frustrating debugging session. And it's nondeterministic. I could try HTTP sniffing my traffic and figuring out their over-the-wire protocol, but that's a lot of work for a question that should be common knowledge, no?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All timed events are stopped and logged when a user backgrounds the app. I don't think that session end triggers it.

Answer (score -1):

Answer to your questions is [here](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ/IOS#How_are_sessions_in_iOS_counted.3F)

```
What happens if the user leaves the app and the session ends? 
The session ends after 10 seconds after app enters the background state.
You can update this using 

> setSessionContinueSeconds

Does the time get logged?
YES.

What happens if the user leaves the app and then returns before the session ends?
The session continues.
```

Comment: Link-only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow because they often eventually stop working.  Also, your link only answers how sessions are counted; it says nothing about how timers are handled.